# How do users give feedback for the Bicycle SE community?

Tags: discussion, meta

Perhaps a meta question, but where is a good place to express praise/suggestions/concerns for the bicycles.stackexchange.com community?

On many other forums, rarely are people ever as tolerant and patiently attentive as the biggest contributors here. Perhaps it's because those in bike shops learned by experience and get asked "stupid" questions all the time, but you can tell they actually want to help.

Comments aren't necessarily appropriate places to praise because it adds clutter, and questions need to have a relevant inquiry.

Is there is a link or email to express these or other comments? How does feedback work?

Comment: Whoever closes this question is getting visited by three ghosts tonight.   (humour)

Comment: This question is kind-of redundant now its on meta... shall we just close it ?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Bicycles SE

This is where you can leave feedback for the moderators:

https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/

It's where you can suggest features, discuss off-topic ideas, or other issues not directly related to the goals of this community.

Comment: Meta is not just for mods - the community at large can read, post, and vote there too.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to join [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=bicycles.stackexchange.com) which is a realtime IRC-like interaction.

SE has had a chat function for a very long time, but it doesn't get a lot of promotion.

As such, there are not a lot of users participating, but its a good place to get immediate feedback.  Sometimes I ask in other site's chat if a question is acceptable for migration, etc.

Another positive of [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=bicycles.stackexchange.com) is that the scroll back can still be read, if you close/refresh the window, so it's possible to have a slow chat over a long time.